# Mask a column in extjs grid

Tags: extjs

In a scenario where grid has say 6 columns . To load the store for all 6 columns takes too much time , hence getting 4 columns is much faster. Is it possible to load the remaining 2 columns when the data arrives for those columns till then those 2 columns must be masked . How to make this happen?

Comment: You can achieve it by using renderer config...

Comment: At present i have achieved using 2 Ajax requests.with first retrieve first 4 columns data. Later when the 2nd request enters success using columns commit can reflect the other 2 columns on to the existing grid.till then placed a loading message on the cells of the 2 columns.

Comment: @jackass Could you leave the details of how you did it as an answer, please? It would be helpful for others who want to do this.